# Use of Fog Node from Pov-Ray in Blender 2.9

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I have a question that I can't seem to find an answer to either in the Blender Manual and on Youtube.

There is a new node that I noticed today in the compositor with its own category in the add-node panel called the *fog* node, under the category *fog*.

This seems to be an output node, but I can't seem to find out what it is, and how to use it.

If anybody can provide an answer to this, please do!

Here are some images related to this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-use-fog-node/1100761

Comment: Thank you. So this does clarify that this is not a new feature. However, it would be helpful to know how to use this node with Pov-Ray.

Comment: https://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.1/92/#l39